# Angular / RXJS - How to perform logic after a switchMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

In one of my components I have a function that updates a local observable (`album$`) which is then used in my html to display the data (`*ngIf="album$ | async as album"`). This works perfectly fine.

```
  getData() {
    this.album$ = this._activatedRoute.params.pipe(
      tap(params => {
        // Update variables
      }),
      switchMap(params => {
        return this.service.getData(params.id, params.id2);
      })
    )
  }
```

However, a new requirement means that I need to update a BehaviorSubject I have in one of my services. The function above seemed like a great place to kill two birds with one stone.

I would like to perform a `patchValue` and `this.service.obs$.next` once the function above returns it's data.

I do achieve this functionality in a separate component I have, but as I'm not using a subscription in the one above, how would i go above adding `this.service.album$.next(data);` to my above function?

// Example of another function that has the functionality i'm pretty much after, but is subscription based.

```
  getData(){
    this._subscription = this._activatedRoute.params.pipe(
      tap(params => {
        // update variables
      }),
      switchMap(params => {
        return this.service.getData(params.id1, params.id2);
      })
    ).subscribe(data => {
      if (data) { 
        this.service.obs$.next(data);
      } 
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can use `tap()` to perform side-effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pipe in `tap` or `map` to the inner observable. Try the following

```js
getData() {
  this.album$ = this._activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    tap(params => {
      // update variables
    }),
    switchMap(params => {
      return this.service.getData(params.id, params.id2).pipe(
        tap(data => {
          this.service.obs$.next(data);
          // patch value
          // do something else
        })
      );
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: how is switching from `tap` to `map` not depending on side effects? ;)

Comment: I just about to accept the above answer, but now i'm curious about the above question :)

Comment: @Haven: That's a valid point. There's essentially no use in using `map` if the value isn't modified. I've adjusted the answer to use `tap`.

Comment: When you say the value isn't modified, do you mean once it's obtained or if it changes from the source? Wondering if i'm understanding that properly

Comment: I meant, `map` is useful if the data from the observable is modified in anyway and the modified value is returned. But we aren't modifying the data from the inner observable in any way, there is no difference between `tap` and `map` here.

Comment: Gotcha! - Thanks for your time!

Comment: Also, you don't need to have the pipe on the 2nd observable. You can simply add that same tap after switchMap to avoid nesting.